# angular 2 group validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Given simple registration form:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email:['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('.+@.+\..+'),
    ]), this.validators.isTaken],
    matchingPassword: this.formBuilder.group({
    password: ['', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(30),
            Validators.minLength(8)
        ])],
    passwordConfirmation: ['', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
        ])]
    }, {validator: this.validators.match})
})
```

I'm trying to validate password confirmation match so I'm applying match validator to form group. But now I'm facing a situation when the field itself displayed as valid (with green border because all its validators are passing) but group validator are not and I need them to be shown as red.

[image]

So should I change ng-valid to ng-invalid manually or there are some trick to fix this in better way?

Comment: For your particular example, I would put the custom matchingPasswordValidator in `passwordConfirmation` field, because that field's content is only valid when it's matching the password. For more general group validator, I would just have a general error message for the whole group.

Comment: @HarryNinh, the problem with this approach is that If I put match validator to `passwordConfirmation` it will only trigger on this field changes. I mean that if you change `password` field so that it match `passwordConfirmation`, the last will still marked as invalid because validation was not run on that field.

Comment: Ah, you can subscribe to `password`'s `valueChanges` event to call `passwordConfirmationControl.updateValueandValidity()` function.

Comment: SET, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered this question over here [1].

Basically angular does not assume you want to invalidate all fields of a group because the group is invalid. You can complement that information in the template itself.

I do not have your template, but I can more or less assume you can change your controls to be invalidated in the following way:

```
<input [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': registerForm.get('matchingPassword').hasError('nomatch')}" type="text" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">

<input [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': registerForm.get('matchingPassword').hasError('nomatch')}" type="text" placeholder="Confirm password" formControlName="passwordConfirmation">
```

You will likely have to adjust the placeholders and error name returned by the custom validator **match**.

[1] [FormControl`s of nested FormGroup are ng-valid although FromGroup is ng-invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354697/formcontrols-of-nested-formgroup-are-ng-valid-although-fromgroup-is-ng-invalid/42427880#42427880)