# FormControl`s of nested FormGroup are ng-valid although FromGroup is ng-invalid

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a nested form group called 'grades':

Although the nested form group 'grades' has the ng-invalid class applied the children form controls do have applied the ng-valid class.

Why is the invalidation not inherited from the nested form to its controls?

```
this.schoolyearForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [this.createSchoolyear.name, [Validators.minLength(3), Validators.required]],
  endDate: [this.createSchoolyear.endDate, Validators.required],
  startDate: [this.createSchoolyear.startDate, Validators.required],
  grades: this.formBuilder.group({
    bestGrade: [this.createSchoolyear.bestGrade, Validators.required],
    worstGrade: [this.createSchoolyear.worstGrade, Validators.required]
  }, { validator: this.gradesCompare })
});


  gradesCompare(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null
  {
    let bestGradeControl = c.get("bestGrade");
    let worstGradeControl = c.get("worstGrade");

    if (bestGradeControl.pristine || worstGradeControl.pristine)
      return null;

    if (bestGradeControl.value === worstGradeControl.value)
    {
      return { "match": true };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

See the red and green borders:

[image]

On the FormControl`s are the css ng-invalid classes not applied:

```
.ng-valid:not(form)  {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

Therefore they are bordered green, but I expected them to be red!

**UPDATE**

I changed the plunkr of user Ben to this one:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VobcC0Qw1EBDytYdkzru?p=preview

It works as I wished it would work, but it seems like a workaround to me. The multiple ng-class expression are hard to understand...

Please Ben grab this plunkr as yours, post it as solution, but only if you think honestly you would also be satisfied with the solution. If not try to find a better solution please, now that you fully know my requirements.

Others are also welcome to join this challenge, now that you know how the validation/ui/error-messages should really behave.

Comment: this exact question was already asked but no solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938050/angular-2-group-validation?rq=1

Comment: Hey Pascal! I had not seen your UPDATE on the 25th Feb. I was actually tempted to write a UI type component from scratch with integrated validation for the pair of grades that can be used like any other form input control. Would that work better for you? What do you think?

Comment: Hey Ben, hm... not sure wether I understand you. You want create a component with 2 dropdowns of numbers and they are not allowed to be equal? Something like the new equals method in 2.4.6 just negated !equals?

Comment: Yes. Would that make more sense than the current solution?

Comment: Well if you wanna make it really like a Validators.NotEquals would it be good if you tight yourself to 2 dropsdowns? Of course for me it would be good as it is inline with my existing approach. But maybe other want 2 inputs of type number or... don`t know :-)

Comment: What about a form control that takes transcluded form controls and makes sure they are all not equal. So not limited to drop downs nor being two controls?

Comment: Yes that could help some ppl yes :-) Or if you are really bored create a fully featured Register/Login component, which I just need as final part of my app :P btw. I am in the old chat if you want sth :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the specific form controls **bestGrade** and **worstGrade** are valid according to their own validators. Only their group has an error. Angular can't know you which controls you would want to invalidate if the group becomes invalid. You could make the information whether there was that specific group validation error onto the specific controls if you wished, and this would result in them being bordered red when they are invalid OR their group has the **match** error.

Without default, the order in which angular processes group validation and control validation would override any manual adding of ng-invalid on the control when the control becomes valid on its own (required condition fulfilled). This is why I am using another class here **matchError** rather than **ng-invalid**. Otherwise **ng-invalid** would be removed and replaced by **ng-valid** by the control validation after **ng-invalid** is added by ngClasses or equivalent class modification.

So instead of

```
<select formControlName="bestGrade">
```

you could use

```
<select [class.matchError]="schoolyearForm.get('grades').hasError('match')" formControlName="bestGrade">
```

in the same way, instead of

```
<select formControlName="worstGrade">
```

you can use

```
<select [class.matchError]="schoolyearForm.get('grades').hasError('match')" formControlName="worstGrade">
```

Edit:
As OP still had issues while using select tags instead of input (read chat), I have recommended also removing the double pristine-ness requirement from the validator itself (by convention, we normally would check this where errors are displayed instead). Because the OP still has issues, I have prepared a plunkr demonstrating a working dummy (and ugly) version of his app to help investigate the issue.

The plunkr can be found at:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Gt5skDUOXfEaxsZreOkh

Edit 2: plnkr URL updated to deal with class setting order when validation are checked between group and individual group controls

Edit 3: Adjusted the answer here itself to reflect the OP's need for  without defaults as was already setup in the latest plnkr from Edit 2

Comment: I use select-tag instead of input-tag. Beside that I does not work. When the nested formgroup gets a red border because both select values are equal then the ng-invalid is NOT applied to any of those select-tags.

Comment: I only tested with input tags, which worked. Let me see if I can find my tiny version for this case to test it with select tags instead. Or do you maybe have a plunkr?

Comment: I found the dummy code I used to test this, and I see how the select tag does not consistently call the group validation. Once I figured it out, I will provide a new answer. May I please request you update the question to specifically address the select question which seems to be different than other controls? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. Basically the validation does not run at all until BOTH grades are no longer pristine. In the case of input fields it did not matter too much because they could not be the same anyway until they were both input. So adding [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid': schoolyearForm.get('grades').hasError('match')}" should work as long as you don't restrict the validation based on pristine-ness according to my tests. It is common to check for pristine-ness where the error is displayed, not within the validator.

Comment: In other words, I am suggesting to remove  >> if (bestGradeControl.pristine || worstGradeControl.pristine)
      return null; << from your validator :)

Comment: My test with the non working select-tags was already without pristine stuff. So it seems you run out of hints ;-) See my screenshot long ago uploaded there are 2 dropdowns ;-)

Comment: I have run out of hints. Without a plunkr or something like this, I can't reproduce. It works for me on select tags too. Sry.

Comment: I might, but as it is work, it is appropriate for the OP to do that work to help clarify their question. It would also be much less helpful, as my code (taking hints from your question), as I described it already works. Your code has a problem that you are looking a solution for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136611/discussion-between-ben-dadsetan-and-pascal).

Comment: If you add this to your plunkr it fails:   bestGrade: [null,validators.required],
          worstGrade: [null, Validators.required]

Comment: Let's discuss any issues in chat please. There are too many comments here to be useful for other readers.
I have updated the URL for the plnkr. The problem was that the group validation happened before the individual control validation, so the control would remove the class ng-invalid and replace it with ng-valid after ngClasses put the ng-invalid. I added a new CSS class called matchError to dela with this.

Comment: Nice, in angular v2.4.6 https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14052 they did finally the equals validator.

Comment: Nice to know! +1 from me

Comment: I tried your matchError change on my LOCAL code. This worked: [ngClass]="{'matchError': schoolyearForm.get('grades').hasError('match')}" but [class.matchError]="schoolyearForm.get('grades').hasError('match')" did NOT work, that means the RED border did not get red. You have any explanation?

Comment: That is quite interesting. As you can see, in the plnkr it does work. I can't think right now of a reason why class.matchError might not work compared to ngClass.

Comment: Happy to read that you have a solution now for your problem though. So will use go for [ngClass]="{'matchError': schoolyearForm.get('grades').hasError('match')}" ?

Comment: I just tried it again because I could not believe that class.name binding was not working AND it works NOW, seems it was some cache/refresh error!!!

Comment: Does this mean that my solution is acceptable to you?

Comment: As a side note, you probably also want a validation or something that bestgrade is bigger than worstgrade ;-)